# Chrome OS text editor with autosave

Tags: gratis, text-editor, chrome-os, dark-theme

I want an text editor app like this:

- Runs in its own window.
- Works on Chromebook.
- Works with files.
- Autosaves.
- Has a full-page interface mode.
- Has themes or at least has a dark-colored theme.
- Gratis.

There are various tab-based text-editors with autosave that either don't work with files or work with one file at a time.

#### Some apps that almost work

- [Minimalist Markdown Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/minimalist-markdown-edito/pghodfjepegmciihfhdipmimghiakcjf?hl=en)

  - Works with files and autosaves.
  - Only split-screen interface.
  - The theme is locked in bright white (no themes).
- [Caret](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret/fljalecfjciodhpcledpamjachpmelml?hl=en)

  - Works with files.
  - Full-page interface and themes.
  - Lacks autosave.
- [Ain't](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aint/djfldbljimkfcgejdcbccebbdkegnema?hl=en)

  - Autosaves
  - Confusing interface.
  - No themes.
  - Only works with ain't files.
- [md everywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/md-everywhere/epgcecfkfjhjpbglakgiallbmnidomgh/related?hl=en)

  - Works with files.
  - Full-page interface and themes.
  - Lacks autosave.